# MSSQL Query Start and End Date where dates sequential then next row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a mssql table such as the below

**Calendar**
ID int 
CalendarDate datetime 
Available bit 
Booked bit

Example Records are
1
01/09/2023
1
0

2
02/09/2023
1
0

3
03/09/2023
1
0

4
04/09/2023
1
0

5
05/09/2023
0
0

6
06/09/2023
0
0

7
07/09/2023
1
0

8
08/09/2023
1
0

9
09/09/2023
1
0

From this data I need the following
Row 1 - Start Date - 01/09/2023 | End Date - 04/09/2023
Row 2 - Start Date - 07/09/2023 | End Date - 09/09/2023
Dates 05/09/2023 and 06/09/2023 are not available so can be skipped

These record denote the start and end of dates available which will be used on an ical to indicate started and end dates not available.

Please can you advise the best query for this.

I have looked at using lag and lead and diff, this is the difference of the next/ previous row only.

I effectively need the split where the diff is greater than 1 and the start and end dates from the range prior to the split.

Comment: This is a classic "gaps and islands" problem; a search of this terminology will likely give you a wealth of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  One approach uses the difference in row numbers method:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CalendarDate) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Available ORDER BY CalendarDate) rn2
    FROM Calendar
)

SELECT MIN(CalendarDate) AS [Start Date],
       MAX(CalendarDate) AS [End Date]
FROM cte
WHERE Available = 1
GROUP BY rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY MIN(CalendarDate);
```